# How do I count unique rows in php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rowcount

Here's my usual way of counting rows...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
```

This will count all rows, even if I use a WHERE clause, it'll still count every row that meets that condition. However, let's say I have a table, we'll call it tokensEarned (that's my actual table name). I have the following data...

user_id = 1,2,4,5,8,8,2,4,3,7,6,2 (those are actual rows in my table - clearly, user 1 has 1 entry, 2 has three entries, etc.) In all, I have 12 entries. But I don't want my query to count 12. I want my query to count each user_id one time. In this example, my count should display 8.

Any help on this? I can further explain if you have any specific questions or clarification you need. I would appreciate it. Thank You.

Comment: Are you saying you want to do `SELECT *`, but then retrieve the distinct user count, all in a single query?

Comment: I'll expand on this and you can choose to read it. Might give you a little insight. I have a pch-type of website. Scratch cards, etc. to possibly when real money. You can spend your tokens on sweepstake entries. In the sweepstakes entry table, I want to automatically count the number of entries (that is easy) but also the number of UNIQUE users that have entries in the database. So if there's 250,000 entries (rows) and 5,000 users with entries, I want to be able to display the number of users with entries, not all 250,000 rows.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, I believe that's what I am looking for.

Comment: If all you need are counts, then _don't_ select the full records, just select the counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use distinct in mysql to select only unique fields in your table.

```
$query = "SELECT distinct user_id FROM users";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query will yield the distinct user count:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS cnt FROM users";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "distinct user count: " . $row['cnt'];
```

It isn't possible to get all records and the distinct count in a single query.

Whether you use the query above or you return all the actual distinct rows really depends on whether you need the full records.  If all you need are the counts, then it is wasteful to return the data in the records, and what I gave above is probably the best option.  If you do need the data, then selecting all distinct rows might make more sense.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've used both ways of counting, what is the difference between SELECT COUNT As count versus $stmt->rowCount(); ? <-- slightly off topic, just want to know if I should be using one versus the other. I'll try adding distinct in my query and see if that helps.

Comment: @DonaldFaulknor It depends on whether you actually need the records, q.v. my updated answer above.

Comment: I plan to count the two in separate queries. But for one query, I'll count unique users, then all rows in another query. All rows is easy for me. I'll try using the DISTINCT for my solution. Thank You. Also, for this particular task, I only need a total count of the two separate queries. I don't need any other data. For my drawings, I require a minimum number of unique users and a minimum number of total entries. So I need to count each to see if those minimums have been reached.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to the following, this way you only shows the unique `user_id`:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM users";
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan dexter, I'll try that. Thanks.